# How can I enhance Hand of Radiance?

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm pondering an epic level half-elf defender whose core feature is the power [Hand of Radiance](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7151).

How can I enhance Hand of Radiance to be more controllery: enabling slowing, sliding, or any other useful controller debuff?

I'm not interested in cheesing for damage, so [morninglord](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=89) is right out.

Comment: Are you asking for official enhancements, or homebrew?

Comment: Official, RAW, only.

Comment: You say defender - are you taking HoR via being a half elf? Or are you thinking a of tanking up an invoker?

Comment: Half-elf dilettante. To be fair, the question can be broadened to tanking up an invoker... Do you know any way of turning HoR primal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clinging Radiance[<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1567) will keep enemies from hiding. Which is about the lamest "controllery" feature I can imagine :)

Echo of Letherna[<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2021) allows you to make your radiant attacks necrotic, but I don't see any way to take advantage of that.

Power of the Moon[<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1453) causes your HoR to drop the targets' reflex defenses by 2

Comment: Mmm, add in Power of Moon and Power of Winter...

Comment: @Brian Power of the Moon, I managed to miss. Power of Winter makes you HoR Cold rather than Radiant (or Nectotic) and adds damage, and since you'd mentioned not cheesing for damage, I skipped it as it's on  that path.

Comment: Yeah, the only way to do something with cold is with some kind of rider. I haven't found any worth noting though.

Answer (score 2):

**Total Rewrite:** My previous answer was lackluster at best. Let's try again.

**Third time's the charm:** As you pointed out, there is a way to get the thunder keyword within RAW. The [Malec-Keth Janissary](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/paragonpath.aspx?id=222) paragon path that gives you 1d4 thunder damage to all of your attacks. You'll obviously need to MC swordmage to do this.

Now you can start getting creative.

1. [Mark of Storm](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1397): Adds a slide 1 to all your thunder attacks.
2. [Arcane Implement Proficiency](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=1115): Choose orb.
3. [Orb Expertise](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=3146): Adds 1 to all your slides with orbs.
4. [Petrified Orb](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=9019)...: Adds 1 to all your slides with this orb.
5. ...of [Unintended Solitude](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2150): Nice little daily power to zap an enemy out of combat for a turn.
6. [Hamanu's Terrible Roar](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=8105): Adds deafen (save ends) on thunder attacks.

Now you've got a guaranteed slide 3 + deafen on all targets you hit with Hand of Radiance. If you need a little extra, toss in a  [Stormglass Shard](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=8600) for another 6 squares of sliding.

If you're looking for other ways to enhance your controller-ness, take [Astral Wind](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7385) as your other level 1 at-will. Then you can pick up [Rushing Cleats](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2716), [Gauntlets of the Ram](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=446), [Ring of Ramming](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3121) and [Resounding Thunder](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=319) to give you a Close Blast 4 that pushes 6 squares *and* slides 3 squares.

Comment: Well, to use Mark of storm most easily, I'd just MC into malek-keth Janissary. But... yeah tis a hard question.